# Can an MSBuild Item use a Property set by a Target?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

I'm trying to achieve the following with MSBuild: my main project (`MyProject.csproj`) should include a couple `Reference` items, but the path to one of those `Reference`s is the value of the `SomeProperty` property, which is set by a Target. Specifically, the value for `SomeProperty` is parsed from a file using [`ReadLinesFromFileTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task).

Here is the high-level structure of `MyProject.csproj`:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="CreateSomeProperty">
    <!-- Tasks that ultimately set $(SomeProperty) by parsing a value with ReadLinesFromFileTask -->
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="$(SomeProperty)" />
    <!-- Other Reference items -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately, this setup is not working. I see those little yellow triangles under the `Dependencies` node of `MyProject` in the VS Solution Explorer, since the project is looking for a DLL at a path with missing characters. Similarly, when I build the project, I get a bunch of `The type or namespace name could not be found` errors, even though I still see the output from a `Message` Task inside my Target. Presumably, the `CreatePathProperty` Target is running during the execution phase, after the `Reference` items have already failed to load during the evaluation phase.

Is there a way to make a setup like this work? I've tried setting `BeforeTargets="Build"` in the `Target` element, and setting `InitialTargets="CreateSomeProperty"` in the `Project` element, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To achieve what you want, firstly you should make sure that custom target executed before msbuild reads the `assembly and reference` info. For this, try using `BeforeTargets="GetReferenceAssemblyPaths"` or `BeforeResolveReferences`.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer works for your requirements, or you can choose to share the content of your script so that we can check it for you directly :)

Comment: Hey sorry some stuff came up and I havent had a chance to test ur answer yet. Looks promising tho. Only possible issue is I am targeting netstandard2.0, not framework, but I shall see shortly

Comment: They(projects target .net standard and .net framework) use same hintpath format to manage the manual references. And they all use the `BeforeResolveReferences` target in build process. So I guess the answer could also work for project targeting .net standard :) Feel free to test it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can an MSBuild Item use a Property set by a Target?

Yes, I'm sure it's possible if you're in `.net framework project with old csproj format` and what you want is a supported scenario in VS2017(Only did the test in VS2017).

**Tips:**

Normally `msbuild` reads the `Properties` and `Items` before it executes your custom target. So we should use something like `BeforeTargets="BeforeResolveReferences"` to make sure the correct order in this scenario is `custom target runs=>create the property=>msbuild reads the info about references and the property`.

Otherwise the order(wrong order when `BeforeTargets="Build"` or what) should be: `Msbuild reads the info about references(now the property is not defined yet)=>the target runs and creates the property`.

**Solution:**
Add this script to the bottom of your xx.csproj.

```
  <!-- Make sure it executes before msbuild reads the ItemGroup above and loads the references -->
  <Target Name="MyTest" BeforeTargets="BeforeResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Define a TestFile to represent the file I read -->
      <TestFile Include="D:\test.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- Pass the file to read to the ReadLinesFromFile task -->
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(TestFile)">
      <!--Create the Property that represents the normal hintpath(SomePath\DLLName.dll)-->
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="HintPathFromFile" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <!-- Output the HintPath in output log to check if the path is right -->
    <Message Text="$(HintPathFromFile)" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="TestReference">
        <!--It actually equals:<HintPath>D:\AssemblyFolder\TestReference.dll</HintPath>-->
        <HintPath>$(HintPathFromFile)</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**In addition:**

I did the test with `test.txt` file whose content is:

[image]

I'm not sure about the actual content(and format) of your file, but if you only have path like `D:\AssemblyFolder\` in that file, you should pass the `D:\AssemblyFolder\+YourAssemblyName.dll` to `<HintPath>` metadata. Cause the **default** `reference` format with `hintpath` looks like this:

```
  <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
      <HintPath>path\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

Pay attention to the path format! Hope my answer helps :)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I can confirm that this setup works even when targeting netstandard2.0. The Reference items created by the Target still don't show under the Dependencies node in the Solution Explorer, which is a major bummer, but I guess I can live with it. (This MSBuild target is going to be part of a NuGet package, and I was hoping that the generated Reference items would show up under the Dependencies node so that the whole process would look less like gypsy magic).

Comment: I think i once saw similar situation like yours. For me, I test it in VS2017, it works well and the reference displays in solution explorer. Then I share the script to one colleague to test it in his VS2019, the reference actually works since we can use the namespace and methods from the assembly, but it doesn't display in Solution Explorer UI. Good news is that this strange behavior won't affect the build in VS or in CI/CD.I guess VS2019 may use a different way to load the project file and display the UI...

Comment: Correct, the build still succeeds, its just visually confusing that the references don't show in VS2019's Solution Explorer. Seems like a reversion...maybe they'll fix it in a future version

Comment: Sorry for necroing an old thread, but do you know who I would need to bother to get this reversion fixed? I.e., to make `Reference`s added by an MSBuild `Target` show in the Solution Explorer? I assume it would be the MSBuild repo or the VS Dev Community forum, but maybe you have a different recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

In msbuild, *static* items can't depend on *dynamic* properties by design.

Accepted answer provides a work-around: use dynamic items, which, naturally, can depend on dynamic properties. But dynamic items don't show up in the IDE.

When dealing with files, more IDE-friendly approach is to create the item statically and update it when the target runs:

```xml
<!-- Static item definition -->
<ItemGroup>
  <SomeItem Include="item_file" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="...">
  <!-- When the target runs, find the static item using Condition and change its properties -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <SomeItem Condition="'%(SomeItem.Identity)' == 'item_file'">
      <SomeProperty>New Value</SomeProperty>
    </SomeItem>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

There's also an open msbuild issue ([#889](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/889)) to support improved syntax for this:

```xml
<Target Name="...">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Update has the same syntax as Include -->
    <SomeItem Update="item_file">
      <SomeProperty>New Value</SomeProperty>
    </SomeItem>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```